# Vue + TypeScript override `export default Vue`

Tags: typescript, vue.js, amd, typescript-typings

I am trying to use Vue and TypeScript. I am trying to compile to AMD in my tsconfig.

The type definition that comes with Vue.js states in vue/types/index.d.ts

```
export default Vue;
```

However, that causes typescript to compile this:

```
import Vue as "vue";
export default Vue.extend({ ... });
```

essentially, into this:

```
define(["vue"], function(vue) {
  exports.default = vue.default.extend({  ... })
});
```

Notice, that it believes vue should have a property .default, which it does not. Is there anyway to write a type definition that overrides the default vue type definition that states something like:

```
export = Vue;
```

or some flag in tsconfig that tells typescript not to add that .default property to the compiled AMD module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling the `esModuleInterop` compiler option will make TypeScript generate code to check for both `vue` and `vue.default` at runtime.

As you note, the Vue type declaration is inaccurate, but based on [this previous issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6815), I don't know if a new issue about it will be well received.

Comment: I see, the esModuleInterop adds an added helper function in the compiled file.      __importDefault = function (mod) {
        return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
    };  This then turns the Vue import into  { "default" : Vue }.   Thanks Matt.